# robots.txt для yii2 куда его вставить

Tags: yii2

Незнаю куда вставить файл robots.txt, пробывал в корень проекта и в папку web но проверка выдает ошибку 404

htaccess в корневой директории

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(web)
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ /web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^fonts/(.*)$ web/fonts/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^image/(.*)$ web/image/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ web/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /web/index.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Структура базовой сборки yii 2

```
web/ - основная папка сайта, содержит файлы стилей, скрипты, картинки и т.д.
    favicon.ico
    index.php - точка входа
    index-test.php
    robots.txt
```

Если не работает, то нужно смотреть настройки. Другого места для robots, по default, не предусмотрено в обеих сборках.

UPD:

```
    1. В корень Yii файл htaccess:

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)?$ /web/$1

2. В папку web файл htaccess:

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . index.php
```

Документация _https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/start-installation#configuring-web-servers

Yii2 настройка _https://webformyself.com/yii2-nastrojka/

> При настройке Yii, особенно на реальном сервере, возможно не всегда получится использовать файл htaccess. В этом случае можно обратиться к настройке сервера. Суть такой настройки сводится к тому, чтобы изменить корневую директорию сервера и сделать так, чтобы корневой стала директория web.

Comment: а в каких настройках покапаться? у меня не видит ни роботс ни фавикон. может эта проблема быть из за чпу?

Comment: отключил правила в urlManager, положил роботс в корень и в папку web, по прямой ссылке открывает только файл в папке вэб а webmaster yandex не видит его нигде. 404

Comment: Получилось?....

Comment: все настроено по документации=( но нет.

Comment: Если бы все, то проблемы не было - попробуйте поставить из коробки и посмотрите результат. Или проблема с сервером/локалом.

Comment: он у меня теперь доступен по ссылке  /web/robots.txt но как туда направить поисковик?, htaccess настроен верно.

Comment: добавил код htaccess в вопрос

Comment: он у вас должен быть доступен по ссылке в корень, а не в папке, хотя находится должен в папке. У Вас не настроен сервер, как надо. Возможно, у Вас nginx, потому не обрабатывает htaccess - если же есть апач или связка апач-nginx, то у вас не то что-то в настройках ваших. Я вам написал, какой htaccess и где должен быть. Или я пишу на деревню дедушке? Ваш htaccess не годится. Два htaccess'а вставьте, как написал Вам, каждый в свое место.

Comment: еще как годится, я вставил код вашего htaccess  иу меня чпу слетело и проблему не решило. но спасибо за помощ=) ответ найден ->  ниже

Comment: Два надо было htaccess вставлять и коды Вам были приведены. Ну, да ладно - ваш вариант забавен, но он хуже приведенного мной и специалистами для корня RewriteRule ^(.+)?$ /web/$1 Думается,что это не последняя Ваша проблема. Удачи Вам и пожалуйста)

Answer (score 1):

нашел ответ 
в корневой .htaccess

необходимо добавить строки

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)
RewriteRule !^/web //web%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

так все работает и robots.txt лежит в папке web но доступен по ссылке /robots.txt